# how to change command for pycharm to convert rst to html

Tags: python, pycharm, restructuredtext, pygments, docutils

I install docutils and pygment for syntax highlighting on rst files.
By using command:

```
rst2html.py file.rst file.html
```

I can get good result.

When I use pycharm to compose rst file, it has build-in script to comvert rst:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2.5.2\helpers\rest_runners\rst2smth.py" rst2html F:/Dropbox/notes/python/PythonNotes/1.rst F:/Dropbox/notes/python/PythonNotes/1.html
```

I read the file "rst2smth.py", it seems use system installed docutils command
rst2html, but I got html without syntax highlight code snippet.
to describe easily, I took a screenshot as below:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/frmf933t3kjcvum/pycharm_rst2html.png

is any way to make pycharm to convert rst to html just like the command I
use in terminal?

and below is the python interpreter setting on pycharm:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qas4352r4fmi6iq/pycharm_packages.png

Comment: You can configure it as an external tool: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-third-party-tools.html.

Comment: it works by using external tool, that I can specify many detailes, thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to change the command used by PyCharm, but you can create your own [External Tool](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-third-party-tools.html) with the desired arguments and bind it to a hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

With the newer version of Pycharm (using 3.4 atm), you have the option to create a target for *Python docs > Sphinx task*. You need to specify the root dir of your docs and the destination dir. You probably need to specifically install sphinx and pygments too.